# jQuery: dealing with multiple keypress listeners?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that needs to do two things at once:

- Listen all the time for input from a scanner (which presents as keyboard input), and notice when a string is entered in the right format.
- Listen for a user focussing on a particular dropdown, and typing a set of initials - when a set of initials is entered that matches the `title` attribute of an item in the dropdown, focus on that dropdown.

I can do either of these things separately, but not together. Code:

```
// Listen for input when userlist is in focus. 
$("#userlist").keypress(function (e) {
    initials += String.fromCharCode(e.which).toUpperCase();
    $(this).find("option").filter(function () {
        return $(this).attr("title").toUpperCase().indexOf(initials) === 0;
    }).first().attr("selected", true);      
    // uses timer to check for time between keypresses
    return false;
});
// Listen for scanner input all the time. 
var input = '',
    r1 = /^~{1}$/,
    r2 = /^~{1}\d+$/,
    r3 = /^~{1}\d+\.$/,
    r4 = /^~{1}\d+\.\d+$/,
    r5 = /^~{1}\d+\.\d+~{1}$/;
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
    // when input matches final regex, do something  
}
```

If I have both, then while the user is focussed on the dropdown, the page does not 'hear' the input from the scanner.

How can I combine the two together to make sure the page reacts to scanner input, even while the user is focussed on the dropdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are overriding the listener on the window object with a listener on the keypress object. I would do something like this:

```
var input = '',
r1 = /^~{1}$/,
r2 = /^~{1}\d+$/,
r3 = /^~{1}\d+\.$/,
r4 = /^~{1}\d+\.\d+$/,
r5 = /^~{1}\d+\.\d+~{1}$/;
function checkRegex(e) { /* Check */ }

// Listen for input when userlist is in focus. 
$("#userlist").keypress(function (e) {
        checkRegex(e);
    initials += String.fromCharCode(e.which).toUpperCase();
    $(this).find("option").filter(function () {
        return $(this).attr("title").toUpperCase().indexOf(initials) === 0;
    }).first().attr("selected", true);      
    // uses timer to check for time between keypresses
    return false;
});
// Listen for scanner input all the time. 
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
    checkRegex(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) give you the necessary control? You could then check for the event target and respond accordingly?

ie:

```
$(window).delegate('keypress', function(e){
    if ($(e.target).attr('id') == 'userlist'){
        // something
    }else{
        //something else
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two handlers. Just have a single handler at the window level and then check which element raised the event:

```
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
  var $target = $(e.target);
  if ($target.is("#userlist")) {
    initials += String.fromCharCode(e.which).toUpperCase();
    $(this).find("option").filter(function () {
    return $(this).attr("title").toUpperCase().indexOf(initials) === 0;
    }).first().attr("selected", true);      
    // uses timer to check for time between keypresses
    return false;
   } else {
       // when input matches final regex, do something  
   }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably way more complex than you'd like it to be, but I think it'll fit your purpose.

I tried to make it in the style of a jQuery plugin, and allow you to attach it to any specific object (and customize of it should override bubbling up through the DOM (in the case of your combo box) in addition to allow for windows, etc.

Anyways, try it out and see what you think. I can make modifications if necessary, just need to know what they are.

**Working Example:** http://www.jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/xSMQd/4/

```
;(function($){
    $.keyListener = function(sel, options){
        // avoid scope issues by using base instead of this
        var base = this;

        // Setup jQuery DOM elements
        base.$sel = $(sel);
        base.sel = sel;
        base.keyPresses = '';
        base.validater = null;

        // add a reverse reference to the DOM object
        base.$sel.data('keyListener', base);

        // create an initialization function we can call
        base.init = function(){
            base.opts = $.extend({}, $.keyListener.defaultOptions, options);

            base.$sel.keypress(function(e){
                base.keyPresses += String.fromCharCode(e.which);

                if (base.validator != null)
                    clearTimeout(base.validator);
                if (base.keyPresses != '')
                    base.validator = setTimeout(base.validateInput, base.opts.callbackDelay);

                if (base.opts.preventDefault)
                    e.preventDefault();
                else if (base.opts.stopPropagation)
                    e.stopPropagation();
            });
        };

        base.validateInput = function(){
            var filter = base.opts.filter;
            var reCompare = (typeof(filter)=='object'
                             ? filter.constructor.toString().match(/regexp/i)!==null
                             : false);

            // exception when the input is cleared out
            var input = base.sel.constructor.toString().match(/HTMLInputElement|HTMLSelectElement|HTMLTextAreaElement/i);
            if (input && (!base.opts.preventDefault && base.$sel.val() == ''))
                base.keyPresses = '';

            // regular expression match
            if (reCompare){
                if (base.keyPresses.match(filter))
                    base.validateSuccess();
                else
                    base.validateFailure();
            // traditional string match
            }else if (typeof(filter)=='string'){
                if (base.keyPresses==filter)
                    base.validateSuccess();
                else
                    base.validateFailure();
            }

            // reset string
            base.keyPresses = '';
        };

        base.validateSuccess = function(){
            if (typeof(base.opts.success)=='function')
                base.opts.success(base.keyPresses);
        };
        base.validateFailure = function(){
            if (typeof(base.opts.failure)=='function')
                base.opts.failure(base.keyPresses);
        };

        // run the initializer
        base.init();
    };

    $.keyListener.defaultOptions = {
        // time to wait before triggering callback
        // Give it time to accumulate the key presses and send it off
        // as a compiled package
        callbackDelay: 1000,

        // Filter to apply to the input (can be a string match or a regular expression)
        filter: /.*/,

        // functions to callback when a match has or hasn't been made
        success: function(i){},
        failure: function(i){},

        // would you like this to completely override key input?
        preventDefault: false,

        // stop it from going up the DOM tree (first object to grab the keypress
        // gets it)
        stopPropagation: true,
    };

    $.fn.extend({
        keyListener: function(options){
            // use return to allow jQuery to chain methods
            return this.each(function(){
                (new $.keyListener(this, options));
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);

$('#listen-scanner,#listen-combo,#listen-text').add(window).keyListener({
    filter: /^\d+$/,
    success: function(input){
        $('#output-scanner').text('Match!: '+input);
    },
    failure: function(input){
        $('#output-scanner').text('No Match: '+input);
    },
    stopPropagation: true
});
```

And the HTML I tried it on:

```
<input type="text" id="listen-scanner" /><span id="output-scanner"></span><br />
<select id="listen-combo">
    <option value="AA">Aardvarc</option>
    <option value="AB">Abracabra</option>
    <option value="AC">Accelerate</option>
    <option value="AD">Adult</option>
</select><span id="output-combo"></span>
<textarea id="listen-text"></textarea>
```